# Given directed graph and store locations place a store so that the maximum distance from any city to the closest store is minimized

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a set of cities 1-C, a set of roads connecting them, and a set of existing stores. The roads are 2-way and the distance is given. What I want to find is the lowest city number in which to place a store such that the maximum distance between any city and the closest store is minimized.

What I have done so far is to build the adjacency matrix of all the cities with the edge weights in them. Then, I run floyd-warshall on this to produce a matrix containing all of the shortest paths from each vertex to each other vertex.

I get sort of lost after this. What I do is use the matrix to find the maximum minimum distance from every vertex that isn't a store to every other vertex that isn't a store. Then I choose the minimum of all of these. However, this isn't correct. I'm not sure if I'm on the correct path or not.

Any input would be awesome. Or if you could point me to a similar problem it would be great.Thanks!

If it matters, I'm implementing in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Floyd-Warshall. Now you have `Distance[i, j] == Distance[j, i]` for all pairs of cities.

Then, find `DistanceToNearestStore[i]` for each city `i`. If city `i` has a store, it is `0`. Otherwise, for each city `j`, find the minimal `Distance[i, j]` where `j` has a store.

Now, we find the maximum of `DistanceToNearestStore[i]` - let's call it `MaxDistanceToNearestStore`. This is what we want to minimize by adding one store.

Now we attempt to put a store in each city and see which one gives the best result:

```
for each city s:
    maxDistanceToNearestStoreWithStoreInS = 0
    for each city i:
        cityDistanceToNearestStore = min(DistanceToNearestStore[i], Distance[i, s])
        maxDistanceToNearestStoreWithStoreInS = max(maxDistanceToNearestStoreWithStoreInS, cityDistanceToNearestStore)
    if (maxDistanceToNearestStoreWithStoreInS < MaxDistanceToNearestStore)
        MaxDistanceToNearestStore = maxDistanceToNearestStoreWithStoreInS
        bestCity = s
```

And bestCity is the city you should put the store in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This worked. The only thing I had to add in was a check to see if it was already a city with a store.